# How to keep dynamically added subelement unique when using clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have just managed to being able to dynamically add rows and subrows of a certain form by using javascript and jquery. The layout for the moment looks like the image below.

[image: Layout in HTML]

In HTML the `<div>` for this part looks like this:

```
<div class="controls">
   <form role="form" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="entry">
         <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input id="medication_name" name="names[]" type="text" class="form-control input-lg margin_top" placeholder="Name medication">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select id="medication_type" name="types[]" class="form-control input-lg margin_top">
               <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
               <option value="short" style="color:#FF8000">Shortworking insulin</option>
               <option value="long" style="color:#00B058">Longworing insulin</option>
               <option value="other" style="color:#64B5F6">Other</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-add input-lg margin_top" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <!-- SUB ENTRY START -->
         <div class="subentry">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
               <input id="time_amount" name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control input margin_top" placeholder="Amount">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
               <select id="time_type" name="times[]" class="form-control input margin_top">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Time of day</option>
                  <option value="morning">in the morning</option>
                  <option value="noon" >at noon</option>
                  <option value="evening">in the evening</option>
                  <option value="food">with food</option>
                  <option value="bed">before bed</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
               <button class="btn btn-info btn-add-time input margin_top" type="button">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
               </button>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- SUB ENTRY END -->
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

In my script I clone certain pieces of the html when the + button is pressed and remove it by pressing the - button. The names for the different input's and select's are being kept by using an array. Like for example in the html code above we find `name="names[]"`. The script can be found below:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
            .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
            .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');

    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
        $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add-time', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var controlForm = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.subentry:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.subentry:not(:last) .btn-add-time')
            .removeClass('btn-add-time').addClass('btn-remove-time')
            .removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-warning')
            .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');

    }).on('click', '.btn-remove-time', function(e) {
        $(this).parents('.subentry:first').remove();

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

So as you can see I clone the `<div>`s containing the form elements for either a new medication or a new time the medication should be taken. Now to my actual question. I know I can loop through the array of names (name="names[]") by using for example:

```
$('input[name^="names"]').each(function() {
    console.log(!$(this).val());
});
```

And this can be done for all my arrays: names[], types[], amounts[], types[]. But my problem is, like I previously said, I don't know which time is with which medication because they are not coupled in a certain way, they are just added to the array. So if I would loop through the amounts[] and times[] arrays, I would not know which time is with which medication. Maybe one of you know a solution or know how to edit the code so this will be possible? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need an object array instead of multiple arrays with unmatched elements.

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me to an example or something? This is my first time developping with JQuery so this does not immediately ring a bell for me.